# How to read a particular notation from the Java language specification

Tags: java, notation

While reading Java language specification I've found some notations I cant understand. For example this one

Let C be a type declaration (§4.12.6, §8.1, §9.1) with zero or more type parameters (§4.4) F1, ..., Fn which have corresponding bounds B1, ..., Bn. That type declaration defines a set of parameterized types (§4.5) C2 , where each argument type Ti ranges over all types that are subtypes of all types listed in the corresponding bound. That is, for each bound type Si in Bi, Ti is a subtype of Si[ F1 := T1, ..., Fn := Tn].

What is Si[ F1 := T1, ..., Fn := Tn]? How to read it? Does anybody know? Thanks...

Comment: What did your prof tell you when you asked him/her this question?

Comment: you gave all the definitions right in that paragraph.  look back for what T means, and F.

Answer (score 1):

The same specification describes the notation in chapter 2.

Answer (score 1):

See this bug [thread](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6651719). Especially this sentence which explains exactly what you are asking for:

> So, given a generic type declaration C<U1 extends B1, U2 extends B2
> ... Un extends Bn> a type C<T1, T2 ... Tn> is well formed if and only
> if T1 <: B1, T2 <: B2 ... Tn <: Bn.

Hopefully it will give you better understanding.

Basically the notation itself tells you that each parameter type Fi is actually assigned to subtype Ti.

Comment: My guess is that [x,x,x] is some range. But what is F1 := T1? Somw kind of relation?

Comment: It denotes assignment. Such special character is used to differentiate from equality check. See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)

Comment: I think I found. "Throughout this section, let A1 , ... , An be the formal type parameters of C, and let be Bi be the declared bound of Ai. The notation [Ai := Ti] denotes substitution of the type variable Ai with the type Ti, for 1in, and is used throughout this specification."

Comment: I thought you were asking about the "meaning".  If your main question is about the "notation" - you're correct.  "[]" represents a "set of value ranges", and "X := Y" represents the substitution of supertype variable Y with subtype  "X".  It's kind-of-like (but not identical to) this ASN.1 notation:  http://www.obj-sys.com/asn1tutorial/node18.html

Comment: @zim32 - Please, too, see my comments below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the current Java specification:

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jls-7-mr3-fullv-oth-JSpec/JLS-JavaSE7-Full.pdf

I could not find the reference you quoted above.

Without knowing more about what the paragraph you cited is talking about, we're at a loss to explain the notation any better.

My best guess is this:

- Every Java "method" has a "signature" listing arguments to that function
- Every argument has a "type" (e.g. "T1") which is a "bounded range" of legal values (e.g. "B1..BN").

I would encourage you to look at Chapter 4: "Types, Values and Variables".

Comment: Here it is http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.2

Comment: I'm asking about exactly Si[ F1 := T1, ..., Fn := Tn] this text. I cant figure out how to read this string in human language

Comment: 1) You're reading an old version of the spec.  You'll noticed that the current version no longer has this particular section (it was too confusing, I guess ;)).  2) The title is "Subtyping among Class and Interface Types"  3) All it means is "every class and interface has a type, and every type has bounds".  Nothing more, nothing less really :)  'Hope that helps .. PSM